# How to format and replace groups using RegEx (or Maybe not?) (Java)

Tags: java, regex, grouping, backreference

```
output = output.replaceAll("%(\\w+)%",getVar("$1"));

public String getVar(name){...return formatted;}
```

I have this line of code (In JAVA), and a function called `getVar()` that will give me the value of the variable with the name we want. The function is working perfectly, but this code doesn't seem to look for the groups anymore.

The String I am formatting with this regex is:

```
"My name is %name% and I am %age% years old."
```

And instead of giving me back: `"My name is Paulo and I am 15 years old."` (Because `name = Paulo` and `age = 15`) It gives me nothing back. Instead of replacing the regex with `getVar(name)` or `getVar(age)`, it replaces it with `getVar("$1")`.

Is there some way of fixing it, is this a bug, or intended behaviour? And if it is, how can I get the same result another way?

EDIT:

```
for(String i: varnames){
            output = output.replaceAll("%"+i+"%",getVar(i));
}
```

Does the job for this specific case... But yet, is there a way to use functions inside of `replaceAll()` and maintaining the groups (e.g. `$1`, `$2`) working inside the function?

EDIT 2:

```
//Variables//
    ArrayList<String> varnames = new ArrayList<String>(0);
    ArrayList<String> varvalues = new ArrayList<String>(0);
//end of Variables

private String getVar(String name){
    String returnv = "";
    if(varnames.contains(name.toLowerCase())) returnv = varvalues.get(varnames.indexOf(name.toLowerCase()));
    //System.out.println("\n\n"+name+"\n\n");
    return returnv;
}

private String format(String input){
    String output = input;

    output = output.replace("[br]","/n");  

    for(String i: varnames){
        output = output.replaceAll("%"+i+"%",getVar(i));//This is how I am parsing the variables.
    }

    //Here I want to handle inline functions... for example: a function called 'invert' that would switch the letters. If the input String that is being formatted (output) contains the regex, the function needs to evaluate and replace.

    //How I tried to do it:
    output.replaceAll("invert\((\w+)\)",invertLetters("$1"));

        return output;
    }

public String invertLetters(String input){//Inverts the letters of the String}
```

Comment: Are you using some library for JavaScript? since this looks pretty different for JavaScript, Is it Java instead of JavaScript?

Comment: Could you please specify if it is `java` or `JS` related question? Thanks

Comment: I am using JAVA

Comment: No, it's not "JAVA", you are using _Java™_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by [**codisfy**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1511178/codisfy) it is not clear at all if you are talking about `java` or `javascript`, as you use the `replaceAll` method I will consider that you use `java`. *However what I will explain hereunder is valid for most (if not all) regex engines independently about the programming language.*

When you call `outputString=inputString.replaceAll("REGEX","REPLACEMENT");` the method `replaceAll` will configure its internal regex engine, build a finite automaton (for simplicity let's omit the difference between `DFA`/`NFA` here) with the regex passed as parameter and analyse the `inputString` on which it is called in order to do the replacement and return the result (`outputString`).

When the method is called it also needs a replacement `String` (`REPLACEMENT`) that is a normal string which may contain or not **back-references** to some groups, in order to enable some contextual replacement (using the syntax `$1`, `$2` or `\1`, `\2`,... depending on the language).

What is very important to understand is that **the regex as well as its replacement string are both just simple strings with no special meaning outside the regex engine** (the method `replaceAll`).

Therefore, if you reuse them in other methods (for example by passing them as parameters) they will be interpreted `literally` as it is the case with other normal strings.

So do **not** expect that `$1` is replaced by `name` or `age` in your call `getVar("$1")`. It will be just `$1` and nothing else.

Also, this being said, your method `public void getVar(name){...}` does not even return a string since its return type is `void`, as consequence, if you code in `java` and if you use `replaceAll` method of String class (which expects 2 strings as arguments) it will **NOT even compile** in the first place.

I will let you implement the rest of the code but if you change your replacement loop in the following way it should work:

```
String input="My name is %name% and I am %age% years old.";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("%(\\w+)%").matcher(input);
String output=new String(input);
while (matcher.find()) {
          System.out.println("------------------------------------");
          System.out.println("Back reference:" + matcher.group(1));
          String group=matcher.group(1);//give access to the first matching group so that it can be reused
          output=output.replaceAll("%"+group+"%", getVar(group));
       }

System.out.println(output);
```

`getVar` method code: (I will let you adapt it)

```
public static String getVar(String name){ 
    if(name.equals("name"))
        return "Paulo"; 
    return "15"; 
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
------------------------------------
Back reference:name
------------------------------------
Back reference:age
My name is Paulo and I am 15 years old.
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I have updated the types of the functions (from void to String) but that was just a typo on the question. So... that means that even if we use the function as a parameter, it won't parse the value of "$1" because it wasn't specified before the function ran? Is there some other way (maybe that doesn't use regex/replaceAll()) to accomplish this result...? I want to do some inline formatting and functions.

Comment: @HenriPK: yes the function `getVar` will received `$1` as plain string and not `name` or `age`. Could you also add the code of your `getVar` method so we can find a better way of doing?

Comment: Alright Allan, I have made an edit with part of my code. And an example to clarify what I mean!

Comment: @HenriPK: I have edited my code as well with the replacement to `replaceAll` ;-) I will let you finish the implementation! Good luck ;-)